# Problem with reading in parameters with special characters in Python

Tags: python, shell, parameter-passing, csh

I have a scripts (a.py) reads in 2 parameters like this:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
username = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
```

Problem is, when I call the script with some special characters:-

```
a.py   "Lionel"   "my*password"
```

It gives me this error:-

```
/swdev/tools/python/current/linux64/bin/python: No match.
```

Any workaround for this?

Comment: The quotes should stop the shell from trying to glob the *. What does a.py's shebang line look like, and is python actually installed at /swdev/tools/python/current/linux64/bin/python?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce, are you sure the error occurs when reading `sys.argv`?

Comment: Since shell commands may be logged and are viewable by all users on a machine, it's not a good idea to input passwords as command-line arguments.

Comment: Definitely unrelated to python, since python errors never look like that. The shebang (`#!`...) is probably the problem.

Comment: Editted the question, putting in the shebang line. Yupe. The python is definitely installed at /swdev/tools/python/current/linux64/bin/python

Comment: i tried removing the shebang line, and instead, call the script thru %python a.py "Lionel" "my*password", still gave me the same error. Any idea what's causing it?

Comment: hey, seems like it is a PYTHON issue. I tried it on a PERL script, it works nicely, but it just doesn't work on a PYTHON script. I really wonder why !! >.< (updated the original question)

Comment: Are you sure this is because of the special character? What happens if you pass an argument that doesn't contain "*"? What happens if you run a simple "Hello world" script with the same shebang?

Comment: @Tom Zych: no problem. Works fine. It just happens when the '*' is there.

Comment: As indicated by the accepted answer, this is not a reproducible problem as shown; it depends on something being wrong in the command line that was not shown in the question. I have also rolled back an edit to show irrelevant Perl code. This is **not a discussion forum** and questions should never be "updated", but instead *edited* for clarity. The Perl code did not help understand the problem, nor with creating a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the commands you're actually using, which are not the same as the commands you've shown us.  Evidence: in Perl, the first two command-line arguments are `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]` (the command name is `$0`).  The Perl script you showed us wouldn't produce the output you showed us.

"No match" is a shell error message.

Copy-and-paste (don't re-type) the *exact* contents of your Python script, the *exact* command line you used to invoke it, and the *exact* output you got.

Some more things to watch out for:

You're invoking the script as `a.py`, which implies either that you're copying it to some directory in your `$PATH`, or that `.` is in your `$PATH`.  If the latter, that's a bad idea; consider what happens if you `cd` info a directory that contains a (possibly malicious) command called `ls`.  Putting `.` at the end of your `$PATH` is safer than putting it at the beginning, but I still recommend leaving it out altogether and using `./command` to invoke commands in the current directory.  In any case, for purposes of this exercise, please use `./a.py` rather than `a.py`, just so we can be sure you're not picking up another `a.py` from elsewhere in your `$PATH`.

This is a long shot, but check whether you have any files in your current directory with a `*` character in their names.  `some_command asd*123` (without quotation marks) will fail if there are no matching files, but not if there happens to be a file whose name is literally `"asd*123"`.

Another thing to try: change your Python script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "before import sys"

import sys

print "after import sys"

username = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
```

This will tell you whether the shell is invoking your script at all.

Comment: @lionel319: I see you've accepted my answer, but I still can't tell what the problem was. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

That error comes from your shell, not from Python. Do you have a `shopt -s failglob` set in your `.bashrc` or somewhere?

Comment: I checked, and i don't find the statements in my .cshrc* or .bashrc either.

Comment: BTW, I can't reproduce this at all on my system. Works fine with the special character.

Comment: i'm guess it should be c-shell, since i can only find .cshrd* in my local.

Comment: Try this: type `bash -i`, get a new prompt, then try to run the script.

Comment: @lionel319 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2791/discussion-between-keith-and-lionel319)

Comment: To see what shell you're using: `echo $SHELL` `echo $BASH_VERSION` (for Bash), `echo $version` (for tcsh).

Answer (score 0):

> /swdev/tools/python/current/linux64/bin/python: No match.

I think the problem is that the python env is not set:

Does python run at all on your machine ?